# How do use Global varibales in a function argument?

Tags: java, function, double, boolean-expression

So my issue is that I cannot use my global variables (a,b,c) in my arguments. I need to be able to use them in my boolean function and double function. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

```
 public class triareamain extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    double a, b, c; 

public void DisplayError() {
        side1input.setText("Error");
        side2input.setText("Type");
        side3input.setText("+ Integers");
    }
    public double areaCal(double a, double b, double c) {
        double s = (a + b + c) / 2;
        double area = Math.sqrt(s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c));
        return area;
    }

    public static boolean isValid(double a, double b, double c) {
        if (a > b + c || b > a + c || c > a + b) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

 private void calculatebuttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
        try {
            a = Double.valueOf(side1input.getText());
            b = Double.valueOf(side2input.getText());
            c = Double.valueOf(side3input.getText());

            boolean area = isValid();

            if (area == false) {
                double finalarea = areaCal();
            } else {
                DisplayError();
            }

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            side1input.setText("Error");
            side2input.setText("Type");
            side3input.setText("+ Integers");
        }
```

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately - this lets those with knowledge of the language you need help with to see your question.

Answer (score 1):

`a`, `b`, and `c` are not *global variables*. Java doesn't have that concept. They are *fields* of class `triareamain`.

However you also created *parameters* of the same name, so those names are *shadowing* the fields.

If you wanted the `areaCal()` method to use the fields directly, remove the parameters:

```
public double areaCal() {
```

If you want the method to use the parameters, then pass values in the call:

```
double finalarea = areaCal(a, b, c);
```

If you keep the parameters, I highly recommend that you rename either the fields or the parameters. Shadowing of variable names is ***very*** confusing to the programmer, and will in high probability be the cause of bugs.